# How to add a simple function at top of FirstViewController.h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm writing a simple app with 10 buttons on it.  One button looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)num1pressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // checkSomethingFirst
    self.myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
}
```

Every button needs to "check something first" so rather than copy and paste the lines of code into every (IBAction)num#pressed code segment, I want to call a function called checkSomethingFirst.  Maybe function is the wrong word here?  Nevertheless my function looks like this:

```
-(void)checkSomethingFirst
{
// check first thing
// check other thing
// check last thing
}
```

When I compile my code - which looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)num1pressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    checkSomethingFirst;
    self.myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
}
```

I get an error at checkSomethingFirst; <--- Use of undeclared identifier 'checkSomethingFirst'.

How do I create a simple function or procedure that all of my buttons can use? Note I don't need to return any values as my checkSomethingFirst function simply sets a label to either a 0 or a 1 (probably better off using a bool, except I'm doing the setting on a global label - hence no need to return a bool, I can simply interrogate the value in the label).

Comment: Why do you use `stringWithFormat:` with out suppling a format? you could just a wel do: `self.myLabel.text = @"1";`. This way you are not creating an extra `NSString` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say what object the method should be called on

`[self checkSomethingFirst];`

Comment: That did it - thanks for the speedy response.  I might actually get the hang of this objective-c stuff in half the time that I initially thought, with guys like you helping.  Another 1000 hours of coding and I should start feeling comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your method in the wrong way

```
  - (IBAction)num1pressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self checkSomethingFirst];
    self.myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that method using

```
[self checkSomethingFirst];
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)num1pressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // checkSomethingFirst
    [self checkSomethingFirst];
    self.myLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"];
}
```